# Connecting signals from QML to Qt: var to QList<QString>

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qt-signals

I am trying to connect a signal from QML to a SLOT from Qt. The signal passes a QList variable.

QML:

```
property var cases: ["A", "B", "C"]

signal casesClicked(list cases)
```

Qt:

```
d->m_view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/qml/main.qml"));
d->m_item = d->m_view->rootObject();
QObject::connect(d->m_item, SIGNAL(casesClicked(QList<QString>)), this, SLOT(onCasesClicked(QList<QString>)));
```

The issue I am having is that I don't know how to declare QList from the QML side, so it is taken directly. If I declare it with:

```
signal casesClicked(var cases)
```

then, the signal is not connected, and I if I declare it as a list or an Array it says `"Invalid signal parameter type: list/Array"`

Any tip? I don't have any problems with single int, bool or string. Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it is appropriate to make the connection on the C ++ side since when compiling it does not know the signal created in QML, a possible solution is to make the connection on the QML side. In the following I show an example

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QDebug>
class Test: public QObject{
QQuickView *view;
Q_OBJECT
public:
    Test(QObject *parent=Q_NULLPTR):QObject(parent)
    {
        view = new QQuickView;
        view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("Test", this);
        view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
        view->show();
    }
public slots:
    void onCasesClicked(QVariantList cases){
        qDebug()<<cases;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
#endif

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    Test test;
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.9

Item {
    id: it
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    signal casesClicked(var cases)

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: it.casesClicked(["B", 1, "D"])
    }

    Connections{
        target: it
        onCasesClicked: Test.onCasesClicked(cases)
    }
    // or
    // onCasesClicked: Test.onCasesClicked(cases)
    // if the connection is made in the same item
}
```

Output:

```
(QVariant(QString, "B"), QVariant(int, 1), QVariant(QString, "D"))
```

Comment: The `Connections` element is redundant in this case, as you have direct access to the signal handler hook in this context. You only need the `onCasesClicked: Test.onCasesClicked(cases)` part.

Comment: @dtech Yes, I know, but if the connection is not given in the same item what you say would not work, my example is simple.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC JS arrays are converted to `QVariantList` in C++, so try using that instead.

EDIT:

Ok, it appears that although the above is the default automatic conversion, it doesn't work for some reason when the connection is made from C++.

In this scenario the signal value is converted to a `QVariant` instead, which can directly be converted to a `QStringList` which is convenient. However that approach will not work if you have a JS array with different data types in it, which is perfectly legal and quite frequently used in JS.

`QVariantList` will still work if you pass the JS array as a parameter to a C++ function call thou. So you can iterate each value and handle a "polymorphic" array.

Whether or not it is recommended practice to create connections from to QML objects from C++ depends on the usage scenario, overall, I'd say that it isn't. The recommended practice is to expose the C++ core interface to QML and do the connections from there and to avoid touching any QML from C++ whatsoever. But there are a few corner cases where exceptions can be made.

Comment: I am using the slot from other functions on Qt, so I was trying to avoid to change the type from Qt side if possible... is there any other option?

Comment: No, that's set in the QML engine - JS arrays become QVariantList - as simple as that, if you want, iterate the QVariantList and fill a list of strings from it. Mind you that Qt also has a QStringList specialization which is preferable to using QList<QString>. Keep in mind that JS arrays are not typed, so you need to use variants as a mediator, it is unavoidable. It works out of the box for integers and bools because the type is known.

Comment: ok, thanks. How should I declare the variable on the QML side to recognize it as a QVariantList on Qt?

Comment: You don't have to do anything, any JS array will be converted to QVariantList  when passed to C++. Just as any JS object will be converted to QVariantMap.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, because the slot is not called by setting the connect with QVariantList: QObject::connect(d->m_item, SIGNAL(casesClicked(QVariantList)), this, SLOT(onCasesClicked(QVariantList)));

Comment: just as a reference, it needs to be declared as a QVariant (QVariantList does not work), and then I use: .toStringList()
"When a QML object type is used as a signal parameter, the parameter should use var as the type, and the value should be received in C++ using the QVariant type"
https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.9/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#connecting-to-qml-signals

Comment: Your connection looks bad, what is `this`? You are using `QObject::connect` so the connection doesn't happen in the scope of a QObject.